# Get value from one select & call values for another select from database

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a library project in PHP & MYSQL in which I've created 3 tables in the DB namely: library_books, student_db & issued_books.

There's a page named issue.php which has been created for the admin to issue books to the students. The page has columns like Book_id, Book_title, Author, Class(student's class from I to XII), Student_name & Student_id(text type disabled).

I'm fetching all the book related details from the library_books database itself,

what I want to achieve is when the user selects a value the Class field, the page should automatically get the list of the students' name enrolled in that class & when Student_name is selected from this list, the Student_id should automatically get fetched into the Student_id field.

Here's is the code, plz take a look

```
<select required class='styled-select green semi-square' style='width: 15%; margin-left: 5px;' id='Class' name='st_Class'>
    <option selected='true' disabled='disabled' value=''>Select Class</option>
    <option>I</option>
    <option>II</option>
    <option>III</option>
    <option>IV</option>
    <option>V</option>
    <option>VI</option>
    <option>VII</option>
    <option>VIII</option>
    <option>IX</option>
    <option>X</option>
    <option>XI</option>
    <option>XII</option>
    </select>   
    <select required class="styled-select green semi-square" style="width: 15%" id="st_name" name="st_name">

    <option selected='true' disabled='disabled' value=''>Select Student</option>
<?php
    $query2 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT Student_name FROM Student_db WHERE Class='st_Class'");
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2,MYSQLI_NUM))
{
    $st_name = $row1[6];
    $st_id = $row1[5];
}
?>
    <option><?php echo(isset($_POST['st_name'])&&($_POST['st_name']=='1'));?></option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="st_id" value="<?php echo $st_id?>" name="st_id" disabled/>
```

Comment: And what exactly is your problem? Or is this just a "coding request"?

Comment: @Alex_Odenthal I've already mentioned what I want to achieve, plz read it again, thanks

Comment: Ok. But than you should read the terms of this forum exactly. This is not a place to ask for "others, would you please do my work?!". You do show a problem and explain an error or very exactly something that you want and what you did to achieve it so far. Right now you just posted some code and tell the world what you like this code to do.

Comment: To get to your "problem" - it looks like (from what you describe) you need some ajax code here that reacts on the changes of your dropdowns.

Answer (score 0):

If I properly understand what you need, in order to populate some data from a DB into a div/input using a select option, you can have a look at [jQuery change function](https://api.jquery.com/change/). Straight from the doc:

> Attaches a change event to the select

In you case, you can retrieve a student data from a select list where you have ID's (or ID's from names, it works either way, as long as a name is linked to a unique ID in your DB)

> I will definately **not** write code for you, just show you the path :)

Remember to include jQuery library in the head part of your page :)

Example you can play with:

-> Select list (should come from PHP query, hard-coded here to make it simple)

```
<select id="st_id">
<option value=""> -- select --</option>
<option value="1"> Name 1</option>
<option value="2"> Name 2</option>
<option value="3"> Name 3</option>
</select>
<p>RESPONSE : <input type="text" name="response" id="response" value="" /></p>
```

-> Jquery part:

```
$(document).ready( function() { // to make sure it's all loaded before use

$("#st_id").on('change', function() { // #st_id is the ID of your select
          var id = $(this).val(); // to catch the value of the selected option
          $.ajax({
           url: "select_get_data.php", // page that will catch/handle the ID and retrieve data from DB accordingly
           method: "POST",
           data: "id="+id, // the selected ID
           success: function(resp){ // if PHP sends correct answer
           $("#response").val(''+resp+''); // #response is the ID of the div/input where data response will be populated
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(request.responseText);
            }
          });
         });
});
```

-> PHP part

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); // to handle errors if any

$id = $_POST['id']; // from AJAX -> here, you must perfom some checking
// never ever trust data from users !!!

echo"Name is MYNAME with ID #$id"; // this will be the response handled in JS by the line
// success: function(resp){ // your echo will be known as 'resp'

// of course, you need to write all checking and query instead of just echo'ing
// but that's the way it works...
?>
```

> hope this helps...